# React hooks how to determine if property of object has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to capture when a property of an object passed as prop to my componet has changed. The scenario is that `myObj` prop might be null in the moment the component is mounted, so this gives me back an error:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   // ...
}, [myObj.myValue]);
```

Since `myObj` is undefined the first load of the component.

This is what I want to say:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (this.props.myObj && this.props.myObj.myValue !== prevProps.myObj.myValue) {
      //...
   }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I am not sure I understand what you are saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in the array is compared on each render, so you can pass `null` or `undefined` as the value if `myObj` is `null`. Once it's non-null, pass `myValue`.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
   // ...
}, [myObj == null ? null : myObj.myValue]);
```